# Objective C threads, setting image in iOS tableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, tabs

I've just started using threads and I'm trying to get better performance from my TableView in my app. Each tableViewCell has an imageView and the image is loaded from disk when the tableViewCell is created. I want to load the Image on a differant thread, then set the UIImageView on the main thread. My question is, can a method that is being ran on another thread return a value to the main thread? Is there a better approach for doin this?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe something like this, assuming your icons are in the document's directory:

```
#define DOCUMENTS_DIRECTORY [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]

//inside - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
NSDictionary *d = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:indexPath, @"indexPath", @"image1.png", @"imageName", nil];
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadIcon:) toTarget:self withObject:d];
//

- (void)iconLoaded:(NSDictionary*)dict {
    [icons replaceObjectAtIndex:[[dict objectForKey:@"index"] intValue] withObject:[UIImage imageWithData:[dict objectForKey:@"imageData"]]];
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[dict objectForKey:@"indexPath"]]];
}
- (void)loadIcon:(NSDictionary*)dict {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSString *filePath = [DOCUMENTS_DIRECTORY stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", [dict objectForKey:@"imageName"]]];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(iconLoaded:) withObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[dict objectForKey:@"indexPath"], "indexPath", imageData, @"imageData", nil] waitUntilDone:YES];


    [pool drain];
}
```

you will need to keep track of which cells you are loading an image for, so you dont try to load one while it is already loading it. there may be some small syntax errors as i did not compile this, just wrote it freehand.

`icons` is an `NSMutableArray` holding a UIImage for each cell

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!! I never thought of calling a method on the main thread from the other thread.

Comment: whenever you are dealing with the UI, you should always be in the main thread.  this is why i don't create the UIImage in the `loadIcon:(NSDictionary*)dict` function, i just create the `NSData` and pass it to the UI thread

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
https://github.com/foursquare/fully-loaded

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass data to the main thread. See the following method in [NSObject API docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-CJBEHAEF):

```
- (void)performSelectorOnMainThread:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait
```

You get to pass a single object reference in the `arg` parameter.